# EF6 LinQ - Select descendants where matching expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to filter the descendants of School by one expression. Is this possible? I want only the pupils with the Age of "12"

Pseudocode

```
context.Schools.Where(s => s.Name = "Springfield Elementary").Where(s => 
s.Pupils.Age == 12).Select(s);
```

Basically i want a Collection of Schools which has an Collection of pupils where match my expression

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output you want to get. Alsow the code of Schools would be nice.

Comment: first include Pupils
`context.Schools.Include(s => s.Pupils).Where(s => s.Name = "Springfield Elementary" && s.Pupils.Age == 12).Select(s);`

Comment: I cannot use the Include statement this way because "Schools" is an EF Entity. Maybe it is only Possible by creating an anonymous type?

Comment: `context.Pupils.Where(s => s.Age == 12 && s.School.Name == "Springfield Elementary")`

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Schools.Where(s => s.Name == "Springfield Elementary" && s.Pupils.Age == 12);
```

It shouldn't be nessesary to `.Select(s)` school since that's what you are querying.

This returns the Schools that have pupils age 12.
But if you want to select the pupils instead you need to:

```
context.Schools
.Where(s => s.Name == "Springfield Elementary" && s.Pupils.Age == 12)
.Select(s=>s.Pupils);
```

Or as suggested by comments querying the pupils instead

```
context.Pupils.Where(s => s.Age == 12 && s.School.Name == "Springfield Elementary");
```

This assumes that Schools/Pupil looks something like this (code-first POCOs):

```
public class School
{ 
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
}

public class Pupil
{ 
    public int PupilId { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```